# React Native 0.60.4 Upgrade from 0.59.9

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, cocoapods, react-native-ios

Hi all I have had a problem when upgrading to RN 0.60.X.

My project originally didn't have cocoapods so I installed them (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) and have started using the XXXX.xcworkspace file vs the XXXX.xcodeproj.

To get everything to build I need to basically remove everything out of my Linked Frameworks and Libraries except libpods-XXX.a, JavaScriptCore.framework, and libRCTPushNotifications.

[image]

So at this point I have a podfile that looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'XXX' do

  # Pods for XXX
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'


  #pod 'React-RCTPushNotification', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS'
  #pod 'EmailValidator', :path=> '../node_modules/email-validator'
  #pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS' 

  target 'XXXTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
use_native_modules!
end

target 'XXX-tvOS' do
  # Pods for XXX-tvOS

  target 'XXX-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Everything builds and I run my app but I get  : No URL bundle present.

```
2019-08-05 09:37:29.744 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:236] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x7fa27dc00bf0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000010c9110>, executor: (null))
2019-08-05 09:37:29.897 [fatal][tid:main] No bundle URL present.

Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.
```

My appDelegate.m has the following line in it

```
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Any idea how to get the bundle to show up?

I have done some some hacky stuff:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

and then dragged main.jsbundle and assets into the workspace

and when I do get some bundle connection it then tells me No Native Module.

Comment: Have you ensured to close the old node terminal?

Comment: And do an npm install

Comment: yes the terminal window shows up but for some reason it says no bundle URL present - i do get this in the but the terminal does start and is running: terminal node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env: No such file or directory

Comment: check that you are running the snippet in the project folder instead of node_modules folder.

Comment: I am running it in the project folder - when building in xcode it also doesn't pop up a terminal either.  Which it should do if there isn't one active.